# Getting the position of an element being translated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to get the position of a div being translated using CSS3 inside another div with a `overflow: hidden` property.

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates it: https://jsfiddle.net/meeuz3w9

The top position of the element is not updated when trying to get it with jQuery's `position().top`.

I have no idea why this is happening, does anyone have a solution?

**Updated:** This doesn't work on Chrome 44 on OSX, but works on other browsers

Comment: It seems to be working in chrome, what exactly do you get and in what browser?

Comment: I see each interval's `console.log` outputting a different, correct, value. Maybe more on browser, etc? I'm on OSX Chrome 44. This type of stuff's behavior can vary widely by browser.

Comment: Seems to me that's working fine, FF39 W7

Comment: Using Chrome 44 on OSX. Seems to work on Safari and Firefox, I have no idea why it doesn't work on Chrome for me...

Comment: take a look at this [bug report](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/bug-jquery-position-after-css-transform-gives-different-result-on-webkit-firefox).

Answer (score 0):

After playing with it a while, I guess I have an answer:

#### This is a performance issue

Chrome uses the resources to make the animation more fluid making the script to get less callbacks called and less positions updated.

While Firefox uses the resources to keep both updated, wich makes the animation not so fluid, but the script gets more updated positions.

In Chrome the profile of the calls is also very irregular (between 2 and 100 calls per position), while in Firefox keeps under 4 calls per position.

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zoLk9yk8/4/) I tried to get better performance, using a native calculus in a global variable:

```
var position = function() {
    return this.getBoundingClientRect().top - 
        this.offsetParent.getBoundingClientRect().top;
};
```

and avoiding the use of console.log ...

```
var callback = function(){
    var top = position.call(callback.target);
    if(benchmark[top] === undefined){
        benchmark[top] = 0;
    } else {
        benchmark[top] += 1;
    }
};
```

then I found this perfomance difference.

## How to solve it

You can get more info here about the differences between JavaScript animations and CSS animations:
https://css-tricks.com/myth-busting-css-animations-vs-javascript/

So after this reading, I propose the following solution:

#### Do it with JavaScript

The animation you describe is as easy as:

```
$('#bar').animate({
    'translate3d': '-2000'
}, {
    step: function (now, fx) {
        console.log(now);
        $(this).css({"transform": "translate3d(0px, " + now + "px, 0px)"});
    },
    duration: 1000,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false
},
'linear');
```

this way you will be able to handle the position on javascript on every tick instead of asking it to the CSS.

I hope it helps.